# many errors running npm run watch-poll command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm

I tried to remove usused packeges("beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.0" and "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0") from my composer and after that I 
got error running :

```
$ npm run watch-poll

> @ watch-poll /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> npm run watch -- --watch-poll


> @ watch /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"


> @ development /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"

        Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

        Running: yarn add vue-template-compiler --dev --production=false

Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --dev
/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Command failed: yarn add vue-template-compiler --dev --production=false
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --dev

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:653:13)
    at Dependencies.execute (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:53:22)
    at dependencies.reject.tap.dependencies (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:32:22)
    at Array.value (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:24:13)
    at Dependencies.install (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:31:14)
    at Function.dependencies (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Assert.js:77:40)
    at concat.filter.tap.dependencies (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:131:24)
    at Array.value (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:24:13)
    at ComponentFactory.installDependencies (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:130:14)
    at Mix.listen (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:55:44)
    at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
    at Mix.dispatch (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:119:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:13)
    at requireConfig (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:118:6)
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:125:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:15)
    at yargs.parse (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:365:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-07-05T14_34_47_549Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-07-05T14_34_47_571Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-07-05T14_34_47_590Z-debug.log
```

Mentioned files has content :

2019-07-05T14_34_47_549Z-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'development',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--watch',
1 verbose cli   '--watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~development: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development" "--" "--watch" "--watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

2019-07-05T14_34_47_571Z-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch" "--" "--watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

2019-07-05T14_34_47_590Z-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch-poll', 'watch-poll', 'postwatch-poll' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch-poll: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch-poll: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~watch-poll: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run watch -- --watch-poll' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch-poll: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch-poll: Failed to exec watch-poll script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "alaouy/youtube": "^2.2",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.12",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^3.0",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelium/sitemap": "^3.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "mews/purifier": "^2.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": ">2.2.0",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "~2.0",
        "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
        "socialiteproviders/instagram": "^3.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.27",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.1",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^2.1",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^5.3",
        "spatie/laravel-tags": "^2.1",
        "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.2",
        "themsaid/laravel-mail-preview": "^2.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.9",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "willvincent/feeds": "1.1.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],


        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.1.2",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
        "mustache": "^2.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.3.1"
    }
}
```

Also I commented all pusher vars in .env file.
I deleted and recreated vendor and node_modules dirs...
I do not know is this error related to cleraring of packeges ?
Why error and how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of yarn

Comment: Actually from the start of the project I use npm , not yarn :

php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.27

npm -v
6.9.0

$ nodejs -v
v10.15.3

$ composer --version
Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17


After your questions I found yarn dependencies in error log :

I am not sure what these messages are and how happened that how my app has yarn dependencies.
I think I need to remove these  yarn dependencies ? How ? Some config files ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to run npm install vue-template-compiler --dev